# ajax progress bar to reflect foreach loop progress on server

Tags: asp.net, ajax, progress-bar

On the server side of an asp.net web application (C#), I have a list of document objects.  To process that list, I use an ajax call that initiates a foreach loop to go through the list and build an html string that gets returned for display.

During the processing I'd like to poll the server to see how many document objects have been processed (the number of times through the loop).  My way of trying to make this work was to put a counter in the loop that is stored in a session variable.  Then, I try to periodically poll and get that session variable value with a different ajax call.

The problem I'm having is that while the polling ajax call occurs asynchronously from the ajax call that initiates the document processing, the responses do not come back from the server to the polling ajax calls until after the document processing ajax call completes.

Is the session variable somehow bound up with the context of the document processing ajax call and until that finishes, the session variable does not become available?  If so, is there a way around this or another way to achieve what I'm attempting?